# Displaying 'note keys/labels' on Garageband for iOS (specifically iPad)

Tags: garageband, ios

I'm wondering if there is a way to display all the 'note letters' on the keys in the Keyboard on GarageBand for iOS.

At the moment it only displays the 'C notes' - for example C2, C3 and C4.

I have no 'music-based technical knowledge' or expertise and would appreciate any help in being able to see all the notes displayed.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty certain that there is no setting to overlay the note names on each key of the GarageBand-IOS keyboard. It's a reasonable question, and I found it repeated a couple of other times on discussion forums.

I submitted this to Apple as a feature request. I encourage you (and others) to do the same using [this link.](http://www.apple.com/feedback/garageband_ios.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response! This is an essential feature for new users.

Answer (score 3):

In order to enable note labels, you have to open

“Settings” > “GarageBand”

and than you are able to toggle “Keyboard Note Labels”.

[image: Example of the GarageBand settings on iOS 12]

Comment: This should be the correct answer.

Comment: Is there any way to notify the user who asked this question?